# how do i submit a form using get method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webforms

I am aware of sending form values using the method=get

```
<FORM METHOD=get ACTION="test.html">
```

I have a textbox which captures email. When i submit form using the GET method the @ is converted to %40. 
I had read somewhere that Jquery could send the data across by serializing. How can it be done?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is here. Is it about making the `@` not escaped? Since that's correct behavior: the whole point is that it gets escaped, so that your server-side code can read it correctly, without the request being misinterpreted. Sending the form via AJAX won't change that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to submit a form using jQuery [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and GET method, you can do something like this:

If you use PHP:

**Form:**

```
<form action='test.php' method='GET' class='ajaxform'>
   <input type='text' name='email'>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( response ) {
                        alert( response );
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

In **test.php** you can get email like this:

`$_GET['email']`

**More Detail:**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks Naveed.. this is exactly what i wanted :)

Comment: Except you can't get email with $_GET['email'] in a html page, it would need to have either the .php or .phtml extension (unless you set apache to activate the CGI-SCRIPT engine for .html extentions)

Comment: Liam Bailey: Is there anyway you can capture the form values in html page?

Comment: Afraid not. If you want to start processing forms, you will need to start looking at one of the server side languages (PHP is arguably the easiest to learn)

Comment: If you are using jquery there is no need to use the submit() method here just detect click on any button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NAVEED's answer to send all the form. Although if you want to send a single field you can use the [second parameter of the get function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

> jQuery.get( url, **[ data ]**, [ callback(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], [ dataType ] )