# jquery $.ajax is not working. form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python-2.7, bottle

I want use jquery to sent form data to server,
and I follow this page↓

[how do i submit a form using get method in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815032/how-do-i-submit-a-form-using-get-method-in-jquery).

But is not working, has no any window alert.
I don't know why....

I already import the jquery script in head(version 1.11.3).

```
<script src="./static/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this is my script.

```
<script>
    function test(){
            document.getElementById("form_test").submit( function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url     : $(this).attr('action'),
                    type    : $(this).attr('method'),
                    data    : $(this).serialize(),
                    success : function( response ) {
                        alert( response );
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
</script>
```

this is my form code.

```
<form id="form_test" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
    <div class="form_description">
        <p>test.</p>
    </div>                      
    <ul >
        <li id="li_1" >
            <label class="description" for="info">info</label>
            <div>
                <input id="info" name="info" class="setInfo" type="text" maxlength="16" value=""/>
                <label id="infoMsg" class="Message"></label><br/>
            </div>
        </li>           
        <li class="buttons">
            <button type="button" class="mbutton" onclick="test()">submit</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the submit handler from `test()`

```
document.getElementById("form_test").submit(function () {
```

This is not required as the function `test` is being called when user clicks on the button.

```
function test() {
    var $form = $('#form_test');
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I would also suggest you to use jQuery `on()` to bind event

```
$('#form_test').on('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: then what is the value of `this`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a form submit event handler registered in the dom ready handler

```
$(function () {
    $("#form_test").submit(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

In your code, you are calling the `test` method on click of the button, which calls the `form` elements submit function with a callback

Comment: I'm sure you didn't notice `test()` on button click

Comment: Yes I have... but it is a better way to use jQuery event handlers(ie avoid using inline handlers when using jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

As you used inline js in submit button, no need for submit event handle for this. See code below :

```
<script>
function test(){
        var myForm =  document.getElementById("form_test");            
            $.ajax({
                url     : $(myForm).attr('action'),
                type    : $(myForm).attr('method'),
                data    : $(myForm).serialize(),
                success : function( response ) {
                    alert( response );
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
            return false;

    }
```